# How to write concise code for array of inputs in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I am newbie to Laravel, is there a way I can write this code in a cleaner/concise way?
It has an array of inputs:

```php
$answers = $request->answer;
foreach ($answers as $answer){
    $ans = new Answer;
    $ans->question_id=$question->id;
    $ans->answer=$answer['body'];            
    $ans->is_correct=(array_key_exists('check',$answer) && $answer['check'] == 'on')?true:false;     
    $ans->save();
}
```

Possibly like this one:

```
Question::create($request->all() +['quiz_id' => $quiz->id,'imgpath'=>$path]);
```

Comment: If you're looking for advice on your code, you may have more luck on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE 2020-05-29

`array_key_exists()` should not be used as it is now deprecated in newer versions of Laravel. When debugging is enabled you will begin to see warnings.

You can, instead, use Laravel's built-in `Illuminate\Support\Arr` helper and call the [`Arr::has()` method](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers#method-array-has):

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;

$person = [
  'name' => 'sam',
  'age' => 23,
  'location' => 'us',
  'hobbies' => ['week' => 'jog', 'weekends' => 'movies'],
];

Arr::has($person, 'name'); // true
Arr::has($person, 'lastname'); // false
Arr::has($person, 'hobbies.week'); // true
Arr::has($person, 'hobbies.monday'); // false
```

---

Models are very dynamic in the way they accept input.

One way - which I usually prefer to insert input would be to call `create()`.

For instace:

```php
Question::create([
  "question_id" => $question->id,
  "answer" => $answer['body'],
  "is_correct" => array_key_exists('check', $answer) ? 
                  $answer['check'] === 'on' :
                  false,
]);
```

This by-passes your need to initiate the `Question::class` and allows you to simply call insert.

Another powerful tool included with Laravel models are `Facades`. If you want to call a custom method such as `Question::insertNew()` into your model; you can use your `Facade` which will automatically initiate the class and call the function properly - with context in mind:

for e.g.

Question.php

```php
class Question extends Model
{
  public function insertNew( $date ) {
    // do whatever with $data
  }
}
```

QuestionsController.php

```php
use Facades\App\Question;

class QuestionsController extends Controller {

  // all functions

  public function store(Request $request) {
    $question = Question::insertNew([/*question array*/]);

    return response([]);
  }

  // remaining functions

}
```

You really ought to checkout [Laravel's docs on Model's](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent). It explains how their core works, and gives you strategies to improve their built-in functions, within your own custom methods.

---